# invalid scalar hex value 0x8000000 and over

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I found a problem getting hex value from yaml file. It couldn't get hex value 0x80000000 and over.
Following is a sample C++ program.

```
// ymlparser.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main(void)
{
  try {
    std::ifstream fin("hex.yaml");
    YAML::Parser parser(fin);
    YAML::Node doc;
    parser.GetNextDocument(doc);

    int num1;
    doc["hex1"] >> num1;
    printf("num1 = 0x%x\n", num1);

    int num2;
    doc["hex2"] >> num2;
    printf("num2 = 0x%x\n", num2);
    return 0;
  } catch(YAML::ParserException& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
  }
}
```

hex.yaml

```
hex1: 0x7FFFFFFF
hex2: 0x80000000
```

Error message is here.

```
$ ./ymlparser 
num1 = 0x7fffffff
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::InvalidScalar'
  what():  yaml-cpp: error at line 2, column 7: invalid scalar
Aborted
```

Environment

yaml-cpp : getting from svn, March.22.2010 or v0.2.5

OS : Ubuntu 9.10 i386

I need to get hex the value on yaml-cpp now, but I have no idea.
Please tell me how to get it another way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The maximum value for a signed int is effectively `0x7FFFFFFF`. I am pretty sure that is the problem.

Try using  `unsigned int` if you are only going to get positive numbers. Or use  `long long` for both, signed and unsigned numbers.

Comment: Anzurio,

Thanks for your help. It is correct! I could get 0x80000000.

Comment: @kioto, the best way to say that around here is to click the checkmark to accept the answer. :-)